# magento extension deleting local folder

Tags: php, magento

I have created a magento extension which works fine also install correctly from downloader or magento connect.

One problem though when i uninstall it from magento downloader it delete app/code/local folder 
completely. other folder delete correctly.

while creating extension i have used select following to create package xml :

Magento local module file : which points to ./app/code/local

path : Mymodulename

Type : Recursive Dir

If anybody have this problem in past, please help

Answer (score 0):

The setting of the Magento Local Module file should point to your extension inside the app/code/local folder and be of type recursive directory.

```
/app/code/local/Your/Extension
```

If you are using the package manager then you should simply select the option `Magento Local module file` and then add your extension information `Your/Extension` and then select recursive directory.

I really find this blog useful when creating packages.

http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-create-extension-package-images/

Comment: i have used following page http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/7_-_magento_connect/creating_magento_connect_extension_package.. but it still delete the local folder.

Comment: can you copy your code into your question, either that or just the section to do the the magento local module file part.